# C++, request URL changes if I execute it in different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, request, threadpool, libcurl

I'm using restclient-cpp lib for requests (based on libcurl), on C++17, on Ubuntu 18.04.

In my program I need to do periodical get and post requests on different threads. At the beginning of my main I call RestClient::init(), then when I need to send a request I create it, I print it as:

`std::cout << "Request url:\n" << request.url << "\n";`

and then I assign it to my thread_pool to execute in another thread. The other thread calls execute() method in my Request struct:

```
struct Request {
  RequestType type = RequestType::get;
  std::string url;
  std::string body_type;
  std::string body;

[[nodiscard]] RestClient::Response execute() const {
switch (type) {
    case get: { std::cout << " - Inside request.h get. URL:\n" << url << "\n"; return RestClient::get(url); }
    default: { assert(false); }
    }
  }
}
```

The outputs from the first and second prints are as follows:

```
Request url in main thread:
https://api.bybit.com/private/linear/position/list

Pushed to threadpool
Inside request.h get. URL:
t��t.com/private/linear/position/list
```

Of course, the request fails because of unknown url. I don't understand how is it possible that the assignment of the Request object to another thread could modify just the beginning of my url string. If I execute the same request in the main thread it works just fine, but I can't work with that in my program.

Edit; reproducible exaple:

```
#include "../restclient-cpp/restclient.h"
#include "../thread_pool.hpp"

enum RequestType {
  get, post, put, patch, del, head, options
};

struct Request {
  RequestType type = RequestType::get;
  std::string url;
  std::string body_type;
  std::string body;

[[nodiscard]] RestClient::Response execute() const {
switch (type) {
    case get: { std::cout << " - Inside request.h get. URL:\n" << url << "\n"; return RestClient::get(url); }
    default: { assert(false); }
    }
  }
}

Request() = default;

Request(RequestType type, std::string url): type(type), url(std::move(url)) {}
}

Request get_positions() {
  return {RequestType::get, 
  "https://api.bybit.com/private/linear/position/list"}}

void callback(const RestClient::Response& response) {
  std::cout << request.url << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) { 
  RestClient::init(); 
  thread_pool pool; 
  std::function<void(const RestClient::Response&)> callback = [&](const RestClient::Response& response) {
      callback(response);
    };
  Request request; 
  request = get_positions();
  std::cout << "Request url:\n" << request.url << "\n"; 
  pool.push_task([&](){ 
    callback(request.execute()); 
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show (in this question) a [mre] that exhibits this problem?

Comment: @DrewDormann sure, I'm using this lib for the thread_pool: https://github.com/bshoshany/thread-pool

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  RestClient::init();
  thread_pool pool;
  Request request;
  request.url = "https://api.bybit.com/private/linear/position/list";
  std::cout << "Request url:\n" << request.url << "\n";
  pool.push_task([&](){
      callback(request.execute());
    });
}

The callback just contains a print at the moment.

Comment: Can you show the code that produces the output you are getting?

Comment: @NathanOliver Posted a simplified example above!

Comment: @Rbdm please [edit] the question, making sure that your [mre] is complete enough to be _reproducible_.

Comment: You haven't posted enough though.  We need your `main` function to see how you are creating the threads and how you are passing the data to the threads.

Comment: Ok, updated with the full example @DrewDormann

Comment: Added code @NathanOliver

Comment: `std::function<...> callback = [&](const RestClient::Response& response) { callback(response); };` - isn't that creating a recursive lambda? You have a local variable `callback` and a global function `callback()` which both accept the same input. Is the lambda capturing the variable, or calling the function? To avoid that issue, you should rename your `callback()` function with a more unique name, like `callbackFunc()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is just a short version example of my code, in my actual code they are named correctly. The callback functions perfectly if I execute the call outside of the thread_pool

Answer (score 1):

I assume `pool.push_task()` doesn't block until the task is finished, correct? That wouldn't be good logic for a thread queue.

The lambda you are pushing into the pool is holding a *reference* to the `request` object that is local to `main()`.  In your example, `main()` exits as soon as `push_task()` exits, at which time that `request` object goes out of scope and gets destroyed.

Meaning, if `push_task()` is not blocking, the lambda is now left with a **dangling reference**, in which case `Request::execute()` is being called on an invalid `Request` object, or the object is being destroyed while `execute()` is running.  Either way, that is **undefined behavior** that can easily lead to the kind of symptom you have described (amongst others).

You need to ensure the `Request` object stays alive until the lambda is done using it.  Either by:

- having the lambda capture the `request` object by value instead of by reference:

  ```
  int main(int argc, const char** argv) { 
    ...
    Request request = get_positions();
    std::cout << "Request url:\n" << request.url << "\n"; 
    pool.push_task([=](){ 
      callback(request.execute()); 
    }); 
  }
  ```
- creating the `request` object dynamically and not destroying it until after the lambda exits.  You can use a smart pointer to automate that:

  ```
  int main(int argc, const char** argv) { 
    ...
    auto request = std::make_unique<Request>(get_positions());
    std::cout << "Request url:\n" << request->url << "\n"; 
    pool.push_task([request = move(request)](){ 
      callback(request->execute()); 
    }); 
  }
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  int main(int argc, const char** argv) { 
    ...
    auto request = std::make_shared<Request>(get_positions());
    std::cout << "Request url:\n" << request->url << "\n"; 
    pool.push_task([request](){ 
      callback(request->execute()); 
    }); 
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve the problem using [=] instead of [&] and creating the request itself inside the thread that's gonna execute it!